# nodejs fs.writeFile failing after post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I have a file being cropped and loaded on the angular side. Thanks to https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

```
    SignUp2ControllerTest -- $scope.upload -->
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAgAElEQVR4Xmy9CbAk61Ue+GVmZWZl7XX32337db9Veov0tCEhJIyFsc2iwQOefWJmFI7AIIztYBxETNgOIiYM42
Angularjs side.

$scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {

  console.log(' SignUp2ControllerTest -- $scope.upload --> ',  dataUrl);

  Upload.upload({
    url: 'http://test.dev:3000/signup/user/uploads',
    data: {
      file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl)
    },
  }).then(function (response) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.result = response.data;
    });
  }, function (response) {
    if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status
      + ': ' + response.data;
  }, function (evt) {
    $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
  });
}
```

I can see the file in the developer window. My issue seems to be on the Nodejs side.

My issue is on the nodejs side. I have the file name and the file is being copied to the tmp folder with a new name.

```
pofPhil3.jpg
image/png
/tmp/nYCf_p6kI5h4LfMQffNHbRu1.jpg
POST /register/user/uploads 200 8.775 ms - 23
Hello World file.name pofPhil3.jpg
```

I have been trying to get the file and copy it to another folder.

```
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multiparty();


router.post('/user/uploads', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log(file.type);
    console.log(file.path);

    var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(req.files.file);

    fs.writeFile('/Users/testuser/test_hold_files/' + file.name, imageBuffer,  function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Hello World file.name' , file.name);
    });
    res.status(200).jsonp({file: file.name});
});
```

The file is being created and named in the new folder. The problem is the file is not a jpg and its empty.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/Users/testuser/test_hold_files$ ls -alt
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 2 root    root    4096 Feb 27 06:26 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   15 Feb 27 06:26 pofPhil3.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   15 Feb 27 06:16 philipMallCar.jpg
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4096 Feb 27 06:08 .
```

any help is great...thanks..

Phil

Comment: tag your questions with ng-file-upload, nodejs file upload, etc

Comment: I don't think `var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(req.files.file);` is needed, you should be able to save the file without decoding encoding etc.

Comment: still working on this issue.

Comment: Upload.upload({
    url: 'http://test.dev:3000/register/user/uploads',
    data: {
      file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl, picFile.name)
    }, --- this Upload.dataUrltoBlob seems to be my issue. I don't know how to create the POST on NODE to accept this BLOB.

Comment: Blob is the same as File in the request being sent, so if you replace that with an actual file you would probably have the same problem

Comment: Yes..the question is how do I save the file in NodeJS. Should be a simple post but it is not. I googled for hours and do not see any examples of saving this  saving this   data: {
      file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl, picFile.name)
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104763/discussion-between-phil-and-danial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am using for the time being. I am having issues with size of the image not being smaller.

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    util = require('util'),
    fs_extra   = require('fs-extra');
This is my post to accept images.

router.post('/user/uploads', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = "/Users/testUser/test_hold_files/";

        fs_extra.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log("success!")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you were decoding the file instead of just piping it as a stream, or is that what you were struggling with?

Comment: This is an example I found that works somewhat. How would I write it out as a stream from express? 4.0 needs middleware if I am not mistaken..Can you post a better example.? Thanks

Comment: I used formidable.IncomingForm in my answer.can see in my answer I used it..Post a better example if you have one.. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating a temp file, or was that a workaround? Is the intent just upload image -> write to file?